# How to set date range when min and max date are same in Android?

Tags: android, date

I am setting date range from an arraylist. 
It is working fine when the min and max dates are different.

The issue comes when both the dates are same.

**Is it possible to somehow set the date range even if the min and max date are same ?**

```
            //---- Set Date Range------//
            SimpleDateFormat sDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date fromDateRange = null ;
            Date toDateRange = null ;
            try {
                fromDateRange = sDateFormat.parse(dateFilters.get(i).getFromDate());
                toDateRange = sDateFormat.parse(dateFilters.get(i).getToDate());
            } catch (ParseException e) {}
            fromDateFragment.setDateRange(fromDateRange.getTime(), toDateRange.getTime()); // setDateRange is a custom method of my DatePickerFragment class   .

            //------------------------//
```

DatePickerFragment.java

```
package com.example.component;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;


public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    onDateSet mOnDateSet;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

    public DatePickerFragment(Context context){

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, this, year, month, day);
    }

    public DatePickerFragment(){}

    public void setDateListener(onDateSet mOnDateSet) {
        this.mOnDateSet = mOnDateSet;
    }

    public interface onDateSet {
        public void onDate(int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth);
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void setDateRange(long minDate, long maxDate){
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {

        if(view.isShown()){
            dismiss();
            mOnDateSet.onDate(year, monthOfYear+1, dayOfMonth);
        }
    }

}
```

**Logcat :-**

```
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.CalendarView.onScroll(CalendarView.java:1224)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.CalendarView.access$900(CalendarView.java:76)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.CalendarView$2.onScroll(CalendarView.java:1085)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1520)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1707)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2300)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1644)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1428)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14067)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4376)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1807)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4464)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
02-25 02:08:04.569: E/AndroidRuntime(8385):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your logcat error and **setDateRange** method

Comment: try to call this `fromDateFragment.setDateRange(fromDateRange.getTime()-1000, toDateRange.getTime());`

Comment: Added logcat and `setDateRange` method is already there

Answer (score 1):

Some days ago I was also facing same issue..

I set Minimum and Maximum time for particular date and its working fine for me.

```
Calendar mCalendarMax = Calendar.getInstance();
// Set your day - month - year here
mCalendarMax.set(Integer.parseInt(dateMaxData[2]), Integer.parseInt(dateMaxData[1]), Integer.parseInt(dateMaxData[0])); 
mCalendarMax.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mCalendarMax.getMaximum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
mCalendarMax.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mCalendarMax.getMaximum(Calendar.MINUTE));
mCalendarMax.set(Calendar.SECOND, mCalendarMax.getMaximum(Calendar.SECOND));
mCalendarMax.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, mCalendarMax.getMaximum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));


Calendar mCalendarTo = Calendar.getInstance();
// Set your day - month - year here
mCalendarTo.set(Integer.parseInt(dateData[2]),Integer.parseInt(dateData[1]),Integer.parseInt(dateData[0]));

mCalendarTo.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mCalendarTo.getMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
mCalendarTo.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mCalendarTo.getMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
mCalendarTo.set(Calendar.SECOND, mCalendarTo.getMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
mCalendarTo.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, mCalendarTo.getMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

Use miliseconds of above calendar instead of date

```
fromDateFragment.setDateRange(mCalendarTo.getTimeInMillis(), mCalendarMax.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: @RahulGupta but why you want to display datepicker when both date are same?? just display alert dialog instead of datepicker

Comment: It is in my functionality to show a datepicker with a range irrespective that tha range is one or 100 days

Comment: Right. so the date picker should show only one day and rest will be faded right as it happens for normal date ranges. I debugged and whenever i set a data range less than 10, it is crashing

Comment: date range may be atleast one day.

Comment: Can you tell me an example or a link implemented a date picker dialog with date range ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48351/discussion-between-capdroid-and-rahul-gupta)

Comment: @RahulGupta your code looking perfect.. I also used same code. you can do one thing if both date are same then add one day in maximum date.

Comment: Ok. Will do that. Thanks :)